# How to implement Application Record in ruby without rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I've been looking at this repository
https://github.com/stungeye/ActiveRecord-without-Rails to understand how can I implement activerecord without rails.I got some problems. At first I got this error when I tried to run this class:

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'mysql2', database: 'rbuserroom')

# Can override table name and primary key
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = 'user_id'

    def initialize(id, email)
        @user_id = id
        @user_email = email
        @user_room

    end

    def create()
        self.save
    end
    
    # accessor get and set method
    attr_accessor :user_room
    attr_reader :user_id, :user_email
end

usr = User.new(1, "user@user")
usr.create()
```

but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from -:25:in `<main>'
/home/felipe/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:52:in `new': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1) (ArgumentError)
```

it seems that active record doesn't accept the parameters in the creation of the class, in fact after that i noticed that the classes in this example don't contain anything inside, how would active record define the columns of the tables?

i'm used to java jpa and springboot that i have to define all the attributes of the class.
besides i don't know if the active record is really working.
I just want that when I create a new user with my user class, the information persists in the database as an insert, or that it updates when I make a change to my object attribute value.

Comment: Even if you only use ActiveRecord without the other parts of Rails, you still need to follow the ActiveRecord documentation. That means you usually do not have to implement getter and setter methods or `new` or `create`. In the above example, only the non-default primary key config is needed in the class. I suggest reading https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

With ActiveRecord you don't need to specify the column names. It detects them from the DB.

You can just write:

```rb
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'mysql2', database: 'rbuserroom')

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'user_id'
end

usr = User.create(user_id: 1, user_email: "user@user")
```

You can read more about creating models in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html). Especially in [3 Creating Active Record Models](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nicolas is of course right in pointing out that active_record does most of the db work for you. So there is no need fo defining initialize or create or the accessors yourself. But I think the error message is caused by the fact that the databases primary key is automatically set and you may not set it explicitly.

Comment: in that case I must create the structure of my database first right?

Comment: @Atastor thank you for the hint. I've added some links.
The error is not caused by the primary key. It can be set manually if needed. The issue is that `ActiveRecord::Base` overwrites the `new` method and has not the same parameters as `initialize`. It only expects no parameters or a single hash.

Comment: @FelipeCristiano exactly. This is usually done by using [migrations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). Alternatively you can create them by hand.